# sforce.one.navigateToSObject not working

Tags: salesforce1-app, redirect, navigation

in Salesforce 1 its not redirecting to the correct record page in Salesforce 1 but is instead redirecting to the Standard Salesforce Web Browser version of the page.

Here is the code:

```
            <div id="center" onclick="myFunction()">
               <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Submit}" styleClass="button"/>
            </div>

        <script type='text/javascript'>  
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: 'publisher.post', onData:function(e) {
                insertSignature();
            }});                                           
        </script>
        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-36269828-12', 'salesforce.com');
          ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    function myFunction(){

 if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
    // Salesforce1  
    alert("made it");
   var recordId = 'a04B00000011w41IAA';
   var type = 'detail';
   sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId, type);        
 } else {
    // Desktop
   window.location.href = '/a04B00000011w41IAA';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Obvious questions, but you're testing this in one.app? Try going to your console, selecting the VF frame, and entering sforce.one.navigateToSObject('a04B00000011w41IAA', 'detail');

Comment: Yeah I entered that into the console and it said Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigateToSObject' of undefined

Comment: Visualforce pages sit in an iframe in one.app, are you sure your console was in the VF frame and not the top frame?

Comment: In case others are having problems with this one too.. I was having a similar problem, then realized I was using the wrong case.  I was using navigateToSobject instead of navigateToSObject (note the lower vs. upper case O).

Answer (score 1):

On this line in your code:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId, type);
```

Try omitting the second parameter and just use:

```
sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId);
```

Comment: @user5428, Please Mark it as answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Any updates? Did it work for you?

Comment: I finally figured it out. If you use window.location at any point within the SF1 app Salesforce 1 Mobile navigation fails to work through the rest of the clickpath. I was using window.location to redirect from my first VF to another VF page and then using sforce.one.navigation after that. After changing the initial redirect to be through sforce.one.navigation everything worked.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation or online.

Comment: @user5428 you should post that as an answer then to help people who have this problem in the future.